# ng-click is not working in javascript datatable how I can call function in angular controller from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I want to  call SetDataDepartment(data), but i am not able to call. also used $compile in controller

```
table = $('#DepartmentTable').DataTable({
    data: Department.departmentsList,
    columns: [
    {
        title: "DepartmentName",
        data: "DepartmentName"
    }, {
        title: "Colleges",
        data: "Colleges.College_Name"
    }, {
        "title": "Action",
        "data": "Id",
        "render": function (data) {
             var aa = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-Click='SetDataDepartment(" + data + ")'>edit</a>";
             return aa;
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: angular.element(document.getElementById('mainController')).scope().SetDataDepartment(' + data + ')';                                                Here maincontroller is the id of the div where define the controller

Comment: Here another example  angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mainController' ) ).scope().SetDataDepartment(' + data + ')';;